# C# Source Generators Remove Files Before Build

Tags: c#, msbuild, roslyn, sourcegenerators

I am working a source generator that produces utility classes I am expecting other devs to use. I have the generator working perfectly. My issue is with emitting files to disk. I can emit the files to disk by

```
    <PropertyGroup>
         <!--Persist the source generator (and other) files to disk--> 
        <EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>true</EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>
         <!-- The "base" path for the source generators--> 
        <GeneratedFolder>Generated</GeneratedFolder>
         <!-- Write the output for each target framework to a different sub-folder--> 
        <CompilerGeneratedFilesOutputPath>$(GeneratedFolder)\$(TargetFramework)</CompilerGeneratedFilesOutputPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

The Above works out great. However, you cannot run the generator again b/c the types have already been defined.

An easy work around for this is to remove the generated types from compilation. This is not desired because the devs will loose intellicents.

The next option would be to remove the Generated dir during pre build.

```
    <Target Name="CleanSourceGeneratedFiles" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild" DependsOnTargets="$(BeforeBuildDependsOn)">
        <RemoveDir Directories="Generated" />
    </Target>
```

This does work except every other build now fails due to missing files.


You cannot delete the generated files and regenerate them during the source generator due to the symbols already being loaded.


How can I create a source generator that emits files to disk and give developers intellicents?

Comment: You do NOT actually need to emit the generated files to disk.
Add the end of your generator you can add the file to the build process without writing it on disk. Devs will have intellisense and you won't have a conflict when running it again.

Comment: And if you want to check the generated files, you can access them in the solution explorer if you unfold the project => references => analyzers => your code generator (IIRC this is how the items are named)

Comment: @Irwene I find this approach only generates the files when Visual Studio restarts, this is not a desired result b/c the util classes need to be derived while the dev is working.

Comment: I remember that was the case when the generators where still in preview. Now I seem to remember they also run at build time. According to this [article](https://andrewlock.net/exploring-dotnet-6-part-9-source-generator-updates-incremental-generators/) they can even be executed **while** the code is being edited.

Comment: Though I'm quite frustrated I cannot find an MSDN page specifying exactly when generators are run.

Comment: @Irwene It does run at build. My issue is that I was trying to generate .cs files from non C# changes. My Util classes were being derived from python scripts that I wanted wrapped up into C# objects. If you clean then build or make C# changes then the generator dumps off the new files. If you don't then the generator fires but doesn't drop off the files. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a target that removes the folder with the generated files, you can just tell the compiler to ignore it:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>true</EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>
    <CompilerGeneratedFilesOutputPath>Generated</CompilerGeneratedFilesOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
...
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\PathTo\MyGenerator.csproj" OutputItemType="Analyzer" ReferenceOutputAssembly="false" />
    <Compile Remove="$(CompilerGeneratedFilesOutputPath)/**/*.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

This approach would also allow saving the generated code in source control. Also, I'm pretty sure that IntelliSense doesn't rely on these files in any way; it only looks at the in-memory generated code.